# Compile in C using a Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a compiler App in C#, using Visual Studio 2010.

The goal of this program is to compile a code written in either C# or C at runtime and return the results of the compilation.

I have done the C# part, but the C part is the one I have problems. For this one, I've tried to use the Visual Studio Command Prompt. The way I'm coding this part is like this:

1. Create a .c file in C:\ using File.Create.
2. Using a Process, open the Visual Studio Command Prompt and execute the compilation.
3. Capture the output to return it as the compilation results.

However, it doesn't work. It throws and Win32 exception, but I don't really know why.

I've heard something about using gcc. But I thought about using the Visual Studio Command Prompt as a possible solution.

EDIT: I figured out the steps to do it (I think). But the Win32 exception appears when the program tries to do the process.Start() line. I guess this might be a permissions problem, but I don't really know.

Comment: You can't just execute C code from a command prompt. You either have to compile the source into an executable, or else pass the source through an interpreter.

Comment: I thought I clearly stated that step 1 was creating a .c file using File.Create.
Furthermore, this VS Command Prompt does allows your to compile a .c file, using `cl <file>.c`. The only restriction is to be in the same directory the .c file is.

Comment: It would help if you explained which Win32 exception you are getting.  Some context would also be helpful - what code was executing when the exception was thrown for example.

Comment: So it sounds like you have it all figured out, then. You compile the file, then execute it and redirect output to a file. Once execution is done, you can read the file for the output results.

Comment: That's the problem (I think I didn't make that clear, though). When the code goes on the `process.Start()`, is when the program throws me the Win32 exception. I don't know what that error is or why it appears, I guess is something to do with permissions, but I don't really know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine worked on something similar, and helped me to solve this problem.

On steps 2 and 3, I was trying to write the input and read the output using simply the process standard input and output, and also, I was trying to use an .lnk to run the Command Prompt. All those things caused the error.

The solution was:

1. Create two batch files, one to start up the Command Prompt and the other to compile the .c file (those were created outside the program's code).
2. (On runtime) Create the .c file, using the code written. If file exists, delete it and create a new one.
3. Start the process with cmd.exe.
4. Run the batch files, using a Stream Writer to write them in the cmd.exe.
5. Retrieve the output using a Stream Reader.

Fortunately, this worked! Code ended like this:

```
string CompileC (string code)
{
    string path = @"C:\sample.c";
    string results = "";

    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
            File.Delete(path);

        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
        {
            byte[] codeText = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(code);
            fs.Write(codeText, 0, codeText.Length);
        }

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                //This batch starts up the Visual Studio Command Prompt.
                sw.WriteLine(@"C:\Startup.bat");
                //This batch does the compilation, once the Command Prompt
                //is running, using the 'cl' command.
                sw.WriteLine(@"C:\Compile.bat");
            }
        }

        using (StreamReader sr = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            if (sr.BaseStream.CanRead)
                results = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }

    return results;
}
```